# How are item rewards in the crucible rewarded?

Tags: destiny

At the end of any crucible matches there are item rewards, usually engrams.

How is it decided who these items should go to?

Looking at the last couple of matches it seems completely random.

Comment: It seems to me that it is completely random. The additional question also is... Is there a time factor to the drops? As in 'n/(time played) or n/(previous drops in last 24hrs)'.

Comment: I just entered bounty, it was 9 seconds left of the fight when I entered, I managed to get 0 kills and 0 deaths, and I got a decoherent class item engram. It certainly didn't reward me for my effort in the match.

Answer (score 4):

Randomly is correct. I have had wins where not a single person on my team got an item, and I have had losses where Strange Coins were handed out.

Comment: Would you be able elaborate your answer, as @NickSuperb mentions - are there any non-random factors, such as time since last drop? Also is your answer based on just personal experience, or do you have a source which can give us any more insight?

Comment: The general consensus around the internet is that it is random. I doubt very much that there will be anything other than "We cannot discuss how rewards are calculated." or "Mission/Crucible end rewards are completely randomised." as an official answer on this subject. Figuring out how to 'game' the system is not something Bungie want becoming mainstream.

Answer (score 2):

RNG(Random Number Generator) is the ultimate decider on who gets what.

But it *does* seem to favor those who rank lower to encourage them to stick around. If players who lost and did badly only got further insulted by not getting any items out of it.. they would probably not enjoy playing anymore.

Here are some pictures of end-game rewards that seem to prove this point of it favoring lower ranks

[one, an engram is better than blues, even if it's green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFrbu.jpg)

[two, Legendary engram for bottom rank, top rank did get something, though](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Qxer.jpg)

[three, only bottom ranks got something](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvhsA.jpg)

[four, Legendary for bottom rank again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbQEv.jpg)

[five, one item, legendary, last place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B68RD.jpg)

[six, legendary for bottom, blues for top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mYii.jpg)

now, this is a very small sample and I can't say if it's definitive, and without information from Bungie we can't know for sure. That being said, this is a pretty good indication (there is tons and tons more pictures of results screen like this) that the RNG gods favor the weak. In my experience with Crucible, I've never seen a Legendary Engram go to top 3, only bottom 3.

Comment: There may be some sample bias here. I imagine it's the players who scored well and didn't receive a reward who take the screenshots because they felt gypped. Meaning that the majority of screenshots like this would support your theory. In situations where they're awarded they don't take a screenshot (and neither would the lower players since they don't expect to be rewarded for poor performance).

Answer (score 0):

You get rewarded for DPS (Damage per second) so if you kill a lot of enemies at once you should get some nice loot.

Thats why sometimes the people at the bottom of the leaderboard get loot and people at the top don't.

Otherwise it is completely random.

Answer (score -2):

its when your kill/death ratio is 2 of the same numbers like: 4.4, or 6.6 or 8.8 which means 8 kills and 8 deaths, this is how i earn most. and possibly the more crucible marks you have the better chance of a reward